# How to check whether webcam is available on a laptop

Tags: windows-vista, webcam

I have a dell notebook, the problem with that notebook is that there is no webcam ( when I opened up the Dell Webcam application, it asked me to select a webcam, as if the webcam didn't exist). I don't know whether the model I bought don't have a built-in webcam, or whether the webcam software is not properly installed.

Is there anyway to check whether Webcam Is Available on a Dell Windows Vista Notebook through any software applications?

My dell model is Dell studio 1435

Answer (score 1):

Two software applications can help.

1. Device Manager (as NT already mentioned) would list a webcam device if one existed.
2. A web browser (your choice, IE, Firefox, Chrome, whatever) to browse to [Dell's support website](http://support.dell.com) and search for documentation on your laptop.  Here's the [support documents](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/1435/) for your model, but apparently the camera is an option on the 1435, so that doesn't help.  However, if you give their website your support tag, it may be able to tell you whether or not that unit was sold with the option.  (As a bonus, there's a service manual available at the second link.  Just in case you want instructions for taking it apart!)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any built-in web cam you should see it physically on your laptop screen.
And also you can verify it from your device manager in windows.

Comment: That's the thing; when I open up the Dell Webcam, it asked me to select a webcam, as if the webcam didn't exist.

Comment: @Ngu probably because it's optional, so some 1435's have it and some don't.  the software probably presents that same dialog even if you don't have the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the images on the Dell website, it suggests there is a webcam built into the Studio 1435, and as NT says, you should be able to see a little black square in the top centre of the screen casing which would usually be the webcam, if it's there, and you're unable to see if in software it may be worth updating/installing the drivers which can be downloaded [from Dell](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&SystemID=STUDIO1435&os=WLH&osl=en&servicetag=&catid=-1&impid=-1&deviceid=16027&libid=17&releaseid=R213648&formatcnt=1&vercnt=2), they are listed in the "Input Devices" section

Answer (score 0):

the webcam was working for a month or so. Then it decided to stop working out of the blue. Try downloading and re-install but the driver but the error message was all in chinese!!!

I m running on Vista.

Answer (score 0):

If webcam is available and drivers are installed, then it should be listed in device manager. If available and drivers are not installed, it shows up in Other devices section of device manager..

Also, 
Install vlc media player and open Menu Media > open capture device. And see if webcam or anything similar is listed.. If listed and selected vlc should display the live camera..